# Using Rstudio on a distant server without x window available

Tags: r, ssh, server, rstudio

I would like to use rstudio on a distant server (through ssh). The server do not have X window available (only command line). Is it possible to connect my local rstudio to the distant server. FYI R is installed on the distant server.

Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#Server) is for.

Comment: If you're familiar with `docker`, you should take a look at [rocker](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Using-the-RStudio-image). Just spin up a container and access through a browser.

Comment: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/ and http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/